# Convert domain name from DNS to NetBIOS format with C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, networking, active-directory

I'm not sure if I'm using a correct terminology here. I'm coding in C++ for Windows. Say, if I have a domain name as "mysite.local", is there an API to convert it to the NetBIOS domain name, example: "MYSITE"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the [`DsGetDcName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675983%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.  As well as returning the name of a domain controller for the specified domain, this returns the name of the domain.

You'll want to pass both the `DS_IS_DNS_NAME` flag (to specify that the input domain name is a DNS name) and the `DS_RETURN_FLAT_NAME` flag (to specify that the output domain name should be a flat name).

Comment: You got it, my man. Here's how I called it: `DOMAIN_CONTROLLER_INFO* pDCI; if(DsGetDcName(NULL, strDNSDomainName, NULL, NULL, DS_IS_DNS_NAME | DS_RETURN_FLAT_NAME, &pDCI) == ERROR_SUCCESS){strNetBiosDomainName = pDCI->DomainName; NetApiBufferFree(pDCI);}`

Comment: Note that you need to copy any data you want to keep before freeing the buffer.  The code that was added to my answer by a third party had a use-after-free bug.

Comment: What happened to you for the last 10 yrs?

Comment: @c00000fd lost interest, basically.  Too much arguing.

Answer (score 0):

gethostbyaddr with type AF_NETBIOS might do the trick (not tested)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738521%28v=vs.85%29.aspx